# zbar_ros how to install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
My goal is to read qr code from video camera stream.
I am first time trying to install zbar_ros.
I am looking for tutorial to configure and install zbar_ros on Ubantu 14.04 . I did look at http://wiki.ros.org/zbar_ros   but there wasn't enough instructions to install.

Please point me to instructions if they are available somewhere.

I have also read that this package can read video stream directly. So we do not need to install openCV.
Thanks,
Hemant

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219303/zbar_ros-how-to-install/) by [hemant T](https://answers.ros.org/users/23015/hemant-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [..] install zbar_ros on Ubantu 14.04

Assuming you are running Indigo, this should be a simple matter of:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-zbar-ros
```

as that package has been released for both Hydro and Indigo (has the *released* badge on the wiki page you linked, and according to [debbuild/indigo - zbar](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=zbar)). There is no need to build it from source.

As to its usage: the `barcode_reader_node` node subscribes to a `sensor_msgs/Image` topic. Anything that can produce such messages would be suitable as input.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0